# Are symbolic links stored as files or just entries in directories?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

My question is related to the way symbolic links are implemented in Linux file systems.

1. Are they regular files stored (inodes used) or are they just special entries in directories?
2. If they are stored in file systems, how are they distinguished from binary files? Do symbolic links have special magic number assigned?

Comment: Reading `man 7 symlink` should answer your questions

Comment: aren't directory entries in the file system therefore the question makes no sense

Comment: @Jaromanda X The wording corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"It depends".

It depends on the filesystem implementation, and on the length of the link.

For example, on ext4 if the target of the symlink is small enough (60 bytes, or something like that) then it is stored in the inode itself and doesn't use a data block.   However if the target is larger then a data block is allocated and the content stored there.

Other filesystems may not have this "store in inode" option.

Traditionally, a symlink is determined by bits in the "mode" (`st_mode`) field of the inode, in the same way that "directory", "character device", "block device", "FIFO", "Socket" are.   Typically an application could do a `stat()` on the filename (or similar) and then test with `S_ISLNK()` on the result's `st_mode` field.

Comment: I wonder if there's any filesystem that would store symlinks directly in direntries without using an inode (discounting filesystems that don't _have_ anything corresponding to an inode anyway, if there's any such that support symlinks). The ext4 optimization of storing the link target in the inode still makes an inode (and yes, you can make a hard link to a symbolic link. the [POSIX text actually seems to explicitly allow for that possibility with `linkat()`
](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html))